# How to decide if the instance is in final state defined by workflow state machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, workflow, state-machine

In our `rails 3.2` app with gem [workflow](https://github.com/geekq/workflow) , the `workflow` is defined as this:

```
   workflow do          
        state :new do
          event :submit, :transitions_to => :being_reviewed
        end
        state :being_reviewed do
          event :approve, :transitions_to => :approved
          event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
        end
        state :approved
        state :rejected

    end
```

The initial state is defined as `:new` and the final state is `:approved` and `:rejected`. Are there methods to tell:

1.if an instance is in its final (completed) state like this:

```
instance.final_state? #return either true or false
```

2.return the final state of a workflow like this:

```
instance.return_final_state = ['approved', 'rejected']
```

We did not see those methods in `gem workflow` documents and would like to know if there is any implementation of such kind. Or methods leading to such implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a solution we found for `gem workflow`. `Model.workflow_spec.state_names` returns array of state names in the order of they are defined. So the final state would be the last one or last 2 states depending on model. So we can form an array of final states by doing:

```
states_array = Model.workflow_spec.state_names
final_state = []
final_state << state_array[-1]
final_state << state_array[-2]
```

To tell if the state of an instance is in final state, we can do:

```
final_state.include?(instance.current_state) #true if it is, or false if it is not.
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see one, but you can just check with `instance.approved?` or `instance.rejected?`.

And, I guess you could create a convenience method to combine these:

```
def workflow_completed?
  approved? || rejected?
end
```

Comment: The idea is that we want to come out with a universal method handling final states which may be approved, rejected or anything else. So we can not assume approved or any other state is the final state.